# Unexpected occurrence of error 'Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default'

Tags: elasticsearch

I had following as the sort field on query of elastic search initially

```
sort : {"Name" : "asc"}
```

Everything worked fine until I changed it to following version

```
sort : [
      {"Name" : "asc"},
       {"_id" : "asc"}
]
```

I started getting following error

```
Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [Name]
```

I thought this might have something to do with use of _id so changed it to another unique field on the documents let's say subId. Even with subId I am getting same error.  I am not able to understand why I am getting this error with the change only and not otherwise (old sort field)

This is the existing mapping

```
{
    "vm05": {
        "mappings": {
            "1-4534": {
                "dynamic": "strict",
                "_all": {
                    "store": true
                },
                "properties": {
                    "10293965_REF_TO_BILL_TO_PRO": {
                        "properties": {
                            "ParentId": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "include_in_all": true
                            },
                            "ParentLabel": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "lowercase": {
                                        "type": "text",
                                        "analyzer": "mdm_lowercase_analyzer",
                                        "fielddata": true
                                    },
                                    "raw": {
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "10293966_MASTER_ALT": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "lowercase": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "mdm_lowercase_analyzer",
                                "fielddata": true
                            },
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "14653178_NETWORK": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "lowercase": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "mdm_lowercase_analyzer",
                                "fielddata": true
                            },
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "4725_PRT_SYS": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "lowercase": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "mdm_lowercase_analyzer",
                                "fielddata": true
                            },
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "4726_PRO_NAME": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "lowercase": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "mdm_lowercase_analyzer",
                                "fielddata": true
                            },
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "4727_REF_TO_PRO": {
                        "properties": {
                            "ParentId": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "include_in_all": true
                            },
                            "ParentLabel": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "lowercase": {
                                        "type": "text",
                                        "analyzer": "mdm_lowercase_analyzer",
                                        "fielddata": true
                                    },
                                    "raw": {
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "4728_RPR_RATE": {
                        "type": "double"
                    },
                    "4729_RPR_OCCURENCE": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "lowercase": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "mdm_lowercase_analyzer",
                                "fielddata": true
                            },
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "4731_CHGE_BAS": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "lowercase": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "mdm_lowercase_analyzer",
                                "fielddata": true
                            },
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "4732_PERIODICITY": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "lowercase": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "mdm_lowercase_analyzer",
                                "fielddata": true
                            },
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "4908_RPR_COMMENT": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "lowercase": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "mdm_lowercase_analyzer",
                                "fielddata": true
                            },
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "5586986_RATE_ZONE": {
                        "properties": {
                            "ParentId": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "include_in_all": true
                            },
                            "ParentLabel": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "lowercase": {
                                        "type": "text",
                                        "analyzer": "mdm_lowercase_analyzer",
                                        "fielddata": true
                                    },
                                    "raw": {
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "8626875_REF_TO_DEPENDENT_PROD": {
                        "properties": {
                            "ParentId": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "include_in_all": true
                            },
                            "ParentLabel": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "lowercase": {
                                        "type": "text",
                                        "analyzer": "mdm_lowercase_analyzer",
                                        "fielddata": true
                                    },
                                    "raw": {
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "8626876_REF_TO_PROD_HOLD": {
                        "properties": {
                            "ParentId": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "include_in_all": true
                            },
                            "ParentLabel": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "lowercase": {
                                        "type": "text",
                                        "analyzer": "mdm_lowercase_analyzer",
                                        "fielddata": true
                                    },
                                    "raw": {
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "8626877_REF_TO_PROD_HOLD_TYP": {
                        "properties": {
                            "ParentId": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "include_in_all": true
                            },
                            "ParentLabel": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "lowercase": {
                                        "type": "text",
                                        "analyzer": "mdm_lowercase_analyzer",
                                        "fielddata": true
                                    },
                                    "raw": {
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "9358147_K2ND_REF_TO_PRO": {
                        "properties": {
                            "ParentId": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "include_in_all": true
                            },
                            "ParentLabel": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "lowercase": {
                                        "type": "text",
                                        "analyzer": "mdm_lowercase_analyzer",
                                        "fielddata": true
                                    },
                                    "raw": {
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "AttributeMetadata": {
                        "include_in_all": false,
                        "properties": {
                            "AttributeFieldId": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "include_in_all": false
                            },
                            "AttributeId": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "include_in_all": false
                            },
                            "AttributeLabel": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "include_in_all": false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "CategoryId": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "include_in_all": false
                    },
                    "CategoryRACL": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "include_in_all": false
                    },
                    "DefaultLookupCode": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "include_in_all": true
                    },
                    "EndDate": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "include_in_all": false
                    },
                    "IsDeleted": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "IsLatest": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "IsPublished": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "Name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "lowercase": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "mdm_lowercase_analyzer",
                                "fielddata": true
                            },
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "StartDate": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "include_in_all": false
                    },
                    "SubjectId": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "include_in_all": false
                    },
                    "SubjectRACL": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "include_in_all": false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the mapping of your index?

Comment: @Val . Added the mapping to the question , please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your `sort` section to the following, it will work without error:

```
sort : [
  {"Name.raw" : "asc"},
   {"_id" : "asc"}
]
```